# Error initializing GeoApiContext in Java

Tags: google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-directions-api

After upgrading version 0.2.2 of google-maps-services, trying to do the following:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("MY KEY").build();
```

I am getting the error detailed below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 1):

There was a reference to an older version of okhttp in another project I had included. Took 2 hours by I got this to work.